# Is "nea" <- "*nivis" proof that metaphonic diphthongisation occured in Romanian before the loss of intervocalic "v"?

Tags: historical-linguistics, sound-change, romance-languages, romanian

The metaphonic diphthongisation phenomenon is said to have occurred between the 6th and 8th century. But it must have happened before the loss of intervocalic "v", though I have only one example to support my claim and i'm not sure if it's indeed proof of it. nivem/*nivis -> *neave(s) -> nea. I can't find any info on this now, but I remember reading of a vulgar latin place name in the Balkan peninsula mentioned in a 6th or 7th century greek document that presented the loss of intervocalic "v". this is my attempt to recall the word: "ketate" ( <- civitatis ). This shows that "v" was already disappearing in Balkan proto-romance. Would this imply that the so called "umlaut" ( diphthongisation ) phenomenon happened even earlier? Well, there is also the famous "Torna, torna, fratre" episode dated to 587 that doesn't show any sign of diphthongisation in the word "torna" ( expected: toarna ).

the alternative form "neauă" could also be explained from the accusative "nivem". According to wikipedia there was an intermediary stage before the loss of intervocalic "v" where v -> w. Could this stage have been preserved in "neauă" but not in "nea" ( that could be a shortened form )?

I know that all of this is a gross oversimplification, misuse of linguistic tools, and possibly misinterpretation of historical linguistics.I am just an amateur with an interest in Romance languages. So my bad for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. Rumanian didn't have metaphonic diphthongisation like that of South Italian; what it had was the reverse: all mid vowels (Latin *ē, ĭ, ae, ĕ* and the back *ō, ŏ*) diphthongised **unless** a [+high] vowel followed, e.g. *nigrum, nigram > negru, neagră.* Or the rule may have been the converse: diphthongise if followed by a [-high] vowel.

Theoretically, a way to decide this would be to look at words that were stressed and monosyllabic; however I can't seem to find any that ended in a mid vowel in the parent language. Probably the ones that existed in Latin were remodelled or discarded due to a general aversion to lexical-word-final stress, similar to many other Romance varieties.

*nea* is already explained from *neauă < nivem* in the same way as *stea < steauă < stēllam* (both forms currently exist). Therefore there's no need to postulate any unusual monosyllabic forms.

As for *cetate* 'castle, citadel', the deletion of /w/ in various environments and of various regularity started affecting Latin already during the middle Republic. We're looking at a sound change that's been going on for two and a half millenia and is still incomplete - this is also seen in the continued coexistence of /w/ and /w/-less forms.

Comment: Romanian had a reverse metaphonic diphthongisation like German. Can you elaborate on how "stea" being explained from "steauă" helps your point in any way? Steauă is a new form made most likely by analogy with "neauă", as the archaic attested form is "steală" and "steauă" cant come directly from "stellam".

Comment: @SarruKen I'm not aware of German undergoing a reverse metaphonic diphthongisation - could you elaborate? Do you agree with my description of metaphony in Romanian?—I don't see any analogy between *steală* and *neauă* - the loss of singleton /l/ in Romanian is known from elsewhere, while a parallel Latin form **st(r)ēla* is found in Fr. Pt. Occ. and even Dalmatian.—Anyway this is irrelevant because I was talking about a further step from *steauă* to *stea* parallel to *neauă > nea.* It doesn't matter if *steauă* is original or analogical as long as both exemplify the same process of u-loss.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't even have to be *steauă* - this was simply the closest-looking word I could find. It could be anything like *neagră* or *albeală* - all of these show that the diphthongisation happened in a penultimate syllable followed by La. /a/. Whether the consonant is /u/, /l/, /gr/ doesn't matter. To be completely honest I don't understand at all why you think the form *nea* points to any early loss of /v/ in that word, why you say the diphthongisation must have happened **before** the loss of /v/. Indeed, the suffix -eală seems to be Slavic and it happened even there.

Comment: My bad, I meant just reverse metaphony like that found in the history of the germanic languages, while the aspect of diphtongisation is particular to Romanian. I took the word "nea" as evidence for /v/ falling before the diphthongisation of /e/ in that word because that phenomenon could only happen if an open or mid vowel followed in the next syllable. My assumption was that in the absence of /v/ the word would become monosyllabic. But like I found later and included in OP, it is theorised that there was an intermediary stage in the process of losing the intervocalic /v/ where /v/ > /w/

Comment: @SarruKen But if it was monosyllabic, it shouldn't have diphthongised because no vowel follows in the next syllable; moreover even open syllable diphtongisation doesn't affect final vowels in Romance. Therefore even if you had only the form *nea* you would have to postulate that it comes from the 2-syllable *neauă!*—/v/ > /w/ requires postulating /w/ > /v/ first, on no good evidence, because there are still dialects in the south of Italy with /w/. This is a great example where the Occam's razor should be applied. Or are there inherited, non-compound Rumanian words with intervocalic /v/?

Comment: My theory for why "steauă" was made by analogy from "neauă" is that both "stea" and "nea" are monosyllabic and end in the same diphthong( hypothesising the short and long forms of both words were in use in the same region ). But I doubt my theory has any solid basis.

Comment: @SarruKen Again, I don't believe there was any reverse metaphony in Germanic - I'm assuming you mean the Umlaut. This is a type of metaphony, but it's not reverse of anything like Rumanian metaphony is the reverse of Sardinian, south Italian and Portuguese where metaphony is caused by the *presence* of final -i, -u, not *absence* as in Rumanian. The Germanic Umlaut is an example of **regressive assimilatory** metaphony - maybe you mixed up "reverse" and "regressive"? "Reverse" means 'the opposite of what happened in other Romance languages', and "regressive" means 'it works from right to left'

Comment: Yes, I confused "regressive" with "reverse" even though I knew the meaning of both words, maybe because of the reason you theorised. I guess I'm just stupid.

Comment: Also I'm really tired and made another mistake: I said that the diphthongisation of /e/ is proof that /v/ fell before this phenomenon, when I meant the exact opposite, just like I said in OP.